# onchange select run function

Tags: javascript

```
<select onchange="alert();">
            <option>d</option>
            <option>de</option>
            <option>dewe</option>
            <option>dewee</option>
        </select>
```

I want the onchange event of a `<select>` element to display an alert but it's not working.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: It does: http://jsfiddle.net/H4kuk/.

Comment: [Works](http://jsfiddle.net/cggdc/) fine for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work but you can also try this provided you include `jQuery` on your page

```
$(function(){

   $("select").change(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your issue is that the `alert()` call displayed *undefined* instead of the value of the `<select>`.

If you want to see the value of the `<select>`, do this instead:

```
<select onchange="alert(this.value);">
    <option>d</option>
    <option>de</option>
    <option>dewe</option>
    <option>dewee</option>
</select>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/Q6yyR/1/)

---

Or, if you actually are using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
//This is an anonymous function that calls itself with the jQuery object as an argument
//This allows you to use the `$` when making jQuery calls but the code
//will run without modification if jQuery is in noConflict() mode
(function($) {
    //This is the important part
    //Here, we bind to the change event and alert the value
    $('select').change( function(e) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})(jQuery)
```

[jsfiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/qY4YB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should give a string as a parameter in your alert function if you want it to work...